Picking lookup values by matching values in an array
Is it possible (in Excel 2016 functionality) to pick values from a lookup table by matching values in a two-dimensional array?
For instance on a tab "LookupTab" I have this:

On another sheet I have numbers in the A column that shall be looked up in the array (column wise). The value shall be picked from the A column of the "LookupTab" sheet using the first row where the number to be looked up can be found in the array, searching top to bottom through the first row of the array, then through the second:

I can do this with traditional INDEX and MATCH logic nested into one another like so: Formula in B2 is:
=IFERROR(INDEX(LookupTab!$A:$A,1+IFNA(MATCH($A2,LookupTab!$B$2:$B$99,0),IFNA(MATCH($A2,LookupTab!$C$2:$C$99,0),""))),"")
That formula is pulled down the B column and it works.
In reality I have even more columns of the array to use for lookup. In the formula in B2 I can nest deeper by replacing the inner-most IFNA replacement value "" by
IFNA(MATCH($A2,LookupTab!$B$2:$B$99,0),"")
and replacing the column letters B of the newly entered formula part manually by the column letter of the column newly added to the array. This is still doable, but cumbersome and somewhat error-prone.
I am looking for a simple formula without nesting which in the best case is supported by Excel 2016 already. Any idea?

I think before the advent of lambdas etc. you would have had to do something like this:
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$9,MATCH(1,MMULT(N(B$2:C$9=E4),ROW(A$1:A$2)^0),0)),"")
i.e. compare the elements of the two-column range with the current No. to get an array of 1's and zeroes, then find the row totals of that array and match on the first 1 in the array to get the index of the value that you want.

I'm assuming a number can't be repeated in a row of your lookup tab.
Otherwise you could try:
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$9,MATCH(TRUE,MMULT(N(B$2:C$9=E2),ROW(A$1:A$2)^0)>0,0)),"")
